# Django cms url pattern without apphook

Tags: django, django-cms

I need to create an application to display the list of projects and project details.

Information on the project is stored in a separate database, which is not connected with the base model.

I created two plug-in to display the list of projects, and output details for a specific project.

for teachers to cooperate each should have its own page with a URL

```
r'^(?P<project_title>\w+)/$'
```

And I thought to use a URL for choosing with project will be shown in project details plugin.

After reading docs, I found only one way to make it. Make it by apphook.
But if I'll do it this way, it will lose any sense to use CMS.
Because in fact I will do the same work as I won't use CMS.

So my question is about is there any solution to make pattern urls without using apphooks.

Comment: Hello, you only need an apphook if you want to manage your app endpoint through the cms. If I understand correctly, you should be able to add your app urls via an include to your project urls.py before the cms urls entry.

Comment: I want to use parent template(with plugin) in app hook pages

For example apphook project name 'project_detail'
so when I go to http://url/project_detail it all ok, I can use cms editor, but when I go to  http://url/project_detail/test I'll get only a template witch write in view.py, without any plugins.

Comment: I can't answer your question without you adding some code, but first off. To create an apphook doesn't lose a sense of CMS. It does the exact opposite in teaching your app about CMS. I'd seriously recommend watching this video to learn about app integration; https://youtu.be/Dj8dhgmzlFM?list=PLbNxojMo86v42AOM47uhaEFHIJFUM4d6M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In apphook template you should use `placeholder`, so it will use parent template.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    {% placeholder "content" inherit %}
{% endblock content %}
```